# Automatic certification exchange on OpenVPN?

Tags: openvpn

Is it possible to just install openvpn client and login to openvpn server without copying certification stuff from the server to the client manually?

I can use the user/pass authentication with out the client certificate, but it seem that I have to copy the ca file from the server manually anyway.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://openvpn.se/files/howto/openvpn-howto_roll_your_own_installation_package.html

I used this + integrated authentication into active directory. That way my users could easily get the client up and running, yet they still had to also authenticate with the AD + be in a VPNUsers group to successfully connect. This packages all of the configuration into a single installer.

Its a difficult thing, balancing security with usability, but for my users downloading a .rar with the config package would have been way to difficult.